# javascript vs jQuery custom/Global Variables scope

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

as my project gets a little over loaded with `javascript` & `jQuery` scripts, 
i am having problems with my try on separating it all to sections, ...like  into *categories* or *stages* ...

so **before** these two calls,  which are 'current project' calls ,

```aspx
<head>
    //i am loading the jQuery & jQuery-UI... and then :

    // right after jQuery comes my first section of project
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jsV2\jQueryAjaxNoPostBack.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jsV2\stage1.js" ></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
            // is valid in stage1.js , naturally...
            var jsTxtVal = document.getElementById("TBX_TableSelectorFirstStage");

            //and that won't work
            var jQueryTxtVal= $('#TBX_TableSelectorFirstStage').val();
    </script>
</head>
```

and in that separated file i try

```jquery
//stage1.js

//---- before ready()-------
//won't work
var jQueryTxtVal= $('#TBX_TableSelectorFirstStage').val();

//works 
var jsTxtVal = document.getElementById("TBX_TableSelectorFirstStage");

$('document').ready(function () {


var TBX_TableSel = $('#TBX_TableSelectorFirstStage');
var jQueryTxtVal= $('#TBX_TableSelectorFirstStage').val();
var jsTxtVal = document.getElementById("TBX_TableSelectorFirstStage");

$('.someElement's Class).click(function () {

    // this will not work unless i will assign "jQueryTxtVal" right here .

    alert(jQueryTxtVal);


   //and... this will work no matter where the assignment took place .
   //either in main page (i call it "the globlas" of project)
   //or at the top of every "section" of project...

    alert(jsTxtVal );

   });
```

now if I would use  *plain*  `JavaScript` ,  I could even put a section of global variables, for all methods... almost anywhere , like within a `<sctipt></srctipt>` under jquery, in main page `.aspx`

so I would like to know , **how could i use "globals" in jQuery ?** 
or it just the use case for that(?) .. I wouldn't think so...

...I also tried `defer="defer"` on `stage1.js` call , inside head- main page `.aspx`
nothing I try succeeds

Comment: Are you sure you want to create globals? Generally speaking you should be looking to avoid creating global variables in JavaScript. Is the problem more about the fact that your variable jQueryTxtVal does not have a value when you expect it to?

Comment: The general best practice is to minimize the use of global variables. Ideally, you want to have one global variable which acts as the namespace of your application.

Comment: @NathanRussell and @ Sime
good to know i did not think of it , as i have no experience yet ! thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is that your line:

```
var jQueryTxtVal= $('#TBX_TableSelectorFirstStage').val();
```

is outside of the jQuery document ready handler, and is almost certainly executing before the dom is ready.

Try putting it within your handler. This will also aid your code as the variable jQueryTxtVal will be local to the ready handler function and won't be polluting the global scope (something that you should really avoid)

There are lots of patterns to help minimising variables in the global scope, such as the simple namespace pattern. But in essence, variable scope is function scope.